# Amchart x-axis date format month based

Tags: javascript, date-format, amcharts

I'm making Amcharts and you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayanray/4m791cuo/), to display some events and I want to show it based on month. As you can see, I have array datelist which is formatted Y-m-d. And also, I'm using dataDateFormat and minPeriod in MM to show month in axis.

```
var datelist = [
        "2016-01-08", "2016-01-18", "2016-02-18", "2016-04-06", "2016-04-10",
        "2016-04-29", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-11", "2016-05-17",
        "2016-05-23", "2016-06-04", "2016-06-22", "2016-06-27", "2016-06-30",
        "2016-07-05", "2016-07-12", "2016-07-24", "2016-07-26", "2016-08-01",
        "2016-08-04", "2016-08-09", "2016-08-15", "2016-08-20", "2016-08-26",
        "2016-08-29", "2016-09-10", "2016-09-11", "2016-10-08", "2016-10-18",
        "2016-11-28", "2016-12-01"
    ];
```

However, I don't know the function or algorithm to show how many events happened based on month with array data datelist. For example, in array datelist for January there are two events happened, and one event for February. For now, I set manually for every data of datelist, there are two events happened as shown in the graph, exception with March, since March isn't included in array.

Thanks for the help, let me know if there's anything unclear.